# lsb_release error: bash: /usr/bin/lsb_release: /usr/bin/python3: bad interpreter: No such file or directory

Tags: apt, bash, python, python3, 22.04

**After upgrading to Ubuntu MATE 22.04 Jammy from Ubuntu MATE 21.10 Impish**, when I run `lsb_release` I'm getting this error:

```
$ lsb_release

bash: /usr/bin/lsb_release: /usr/bin/python3: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

Relevant commands:

```
$ whereis lsb_release
lsb_release: /usr/bin/lsb_release /usr/share/man/man1/lsb_release.1.gz
```

```
$ python -V
bash: python: command not found
$ python3 -V
bash: python3: command not found

$ python3.10 -V
Python 3.10.4
```

```
$ which python3 or $ which python
Nothing.

$ which python3.10
/usr/bin/python3.10
```

```
$ whereis python
python: /usr/bin/python /usr/share/python /usr/share/man/man1/python.1.gz

$ whereis python3
python3: /usr/lib/python3 /etc/python3 /usr/share/python3 /usr/share/man/man1/python3.1.gz

$ whereis python3.10
python3.10: /usr/bin/python3.10 /usr/lib/python3.10 /etc/python3.10 /usr/local/lib/python3.10 /usr/include/python3.10 /usr/share/man/man1/python3.10.1.gz
```

```
ls -lsh /usr/bin/python*
   0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    7 Oct 11  2021 /usr/bin/python -> python3
   0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    9 Jul 28  2021 /usr/bin/python2 -> python2.7
3.5M -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 3.5M Mar 12 11:54 /usr/bin/python2.7
5.7M -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 5.7M Apr  2 14:34 /usr/bin/python3.10
   0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   34 Apr  2 14:34 /usr/bin/python3.10-config -> x86_64-linux-gnu-python3.10-config
   0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   17 Mar 25 18:11 /usr/bin/python3-config -> python3.10-config
4.0K -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1.8K Aug  6  2019 /usr/bin/python3-unidiff
```

```
$ sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python3.10
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/usr/bin/python3.10': File exists
```

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --config python3
update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for python3

$ sudo update-alternatives --config python
update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for python
```

**The way I found out about `lsb_release` error** is because `mate-menu` (Advanced MATE Menu) stopped working (disappeared from taskbar), and when I tried to reinstall it (using Synaptic), I got this error:

```
E: mate-menu: package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should  reinstall it before attempting configuration

Can't exec "lsb_release": No such file or directory at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/FrontEnd/Gnome.pm line 184, <> line 1.
Use of uninitialized value in lc at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/FrontEnd/Gnome.pm line 184, <> line 1.
(Reading database ... 378043 files and directories currently installed.)

Preparing to unpack .../lsb-release_11.1.0ubuntu4_all.deb ...
Unpacking lsb-release (11.1.0ubuntu4) over (11.1.0ubuntu4) ...
dpkg: error processing package mate-menu (--configure):

 package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
 reinstall it before attempting configuration

Setting up lsb-release (11.1.0ubuntu4) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.10.2-1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mate-menu
```

Though I have found these similar threads, they are not working out for me. Thank you.

https://askubuntu.com/a/919416/928088

https://stackoverflow.com/q/62329393/11855487

Comment: Your `ln -s` command has its arguments switched

Comment: @steeldriver ohh I just saw that and saw your comment at the same time. It's working now. Would you like to make it an answer? Thank you so much as always.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As suggested in @steeldriver comment, I had switched arguments in my `ln -s` command. Reversing it resolved the issue:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python3.10 /usr/bin/python3
```